# Physical transfer speed Java IO

Tags: java, io

Is there a way to see the transfer speed (MB/s) while copying files?
This is not for network sockets but for hdd to hdd for example.
i copy the files content in bytes.
Code for copying files: platform is windows

```
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    totalBytesCopied += length;
    int totalKilos = (int) totalBytesCopied / 1024;
    int totalMegas = totalKilos / 1024;
}
```

A example of how this can be done?
Kind Regards

Comment: What code are you using to copy the files? If you're doing it in a simple loop then it's trivial, you just measure how many bytes you've received in the time since you started the transfer. If you're using channels / NIO stuff then it gets a bit trickier, but can still be done if you initiate the transfer in chunks rather than all in one go.

Comment: Wrap the copy code with code to check the time. Compare data transfered every second.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `hdparm`.  You haven't specified the platform, that'll work on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

A kind of. First you can do it at application level. Your code that copies file should look like:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
```

So, modify it as following:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n = 0;
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double speed = n / (after - before) * 1000; // speed in byte per second 
        before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

You can do better. Implement `SpeedMeasurementOutputStream` that wraps any output stream and performs similar logic into its `write()` method. Then wrap `FileOutputStream` using this stream and get the speed while copying. This approach is better because this way you can measure speed of any stream.

Comment: If i use your example i get java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: @user1794974 The code show only the principle. Dealing with edge cases like zero elapsed milliseconds in the formula is *your* job.